# Xcode's project navigator files icons turned black

Tags: xcode

After updating to Xcode 13.0 (13A233), for some reason, all the project navigator icons turned black.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: Project structure with black icons]

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved it for me was:

Go to **System Settings** -> **Accessibility** -> **Display** -> Check "**Increase Contrast**"

Then you should be able to see the file icons in their original colour again.